# The problem of working with DbContext in asynchronous calls

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, entity-framework-core

I have a problem with my code that uses Entity Framework Core to interact with the database. I created an instance of `DbContext` inside the constructor of the `UnitOfWork` class and access it through repository methods. But when I call Invoke a second time, I get the error "A second operation was started on this context instance before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads concurrently using the same instance of DbContext."

I have already tried to solve this problem by using `using` to create temporary `DbContext` instances, but it didn't help. I also tried using async/await to wait for the previous operation to complete, but that didn't work either.

I can't figure out how to solve this problem. Maybe some of you have faced the same problem and know how to solve it? I will be very grateful for any help!

My code

BotContext:

```
public class BotContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<ChatUser> ChatUsers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TelegramChat> TelegramChats { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TelegramUser> TelegramUsers { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        string connString;
        // ...
        optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(connString);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(BotContext).Assembly);
    }

    public string GetHashCode()
    {
        return base.ContextId.InstanceId.ToString();
    }
}
```

UnitOfWork:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, object> _repsDictionary;
    internal static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, object> cash = new();
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, object> _fieldDictionary = new();
    private readonly BotContext _dbContext;

    public UnitOfWork()
    {
        _dbContext = new BotContext();
        _repsDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, object>();
    }

    public IRepository<TEntity> GetRepository<TEntity>()
        where TEntity : class, IBaseEntity
    {
        if (cash.ContainsKey(typeof(TEntity)))
            return _repsDictionary.GetOrAdd(typeof(TEntity),
                x => new Repository<TEntity>(_dbContext.Set<TEntity>())) as IRepository<TEntity>;
        var rep = _dbContext.Set<TEntity>();
        cash.GetOrAdd(typeof(TEntity), rep.ToArray());
        return _repsDictionary.GetOrAdd(typeof(TEntity),
            x => new Repository<TEntity>(rep)) as IRepository<TEntity>;
    }

    public async Task SaveChangesAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Invoke SaveChangesAsync in context with hashcode: {_dbContext.GetHashCode()}");
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public static void SetField(string name, object obj)
    {
        _fieldDictionary[name] = obj;
    }

    public static T GetField<T>(string name)
    {
        return (T)_fieldDictionary[name];
    }

    private bool _disposed;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual async Task Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"dispose call for UoW with hashcode {this.GetHashCode()} and contextId {_dbContext.GetHashCode()}");
        if (_disposed) return;

        if (disposing)
        {
            await _dbContext.DisposeAsync();
        }

        _disposed = true;
    }

    ~UnitOfWork() => Dispose(false);
}
```

The code in which the problem occurs:

```
public class DALTestCommand : IConsoleCommand
{
    public string CommandName { get; set; } = "daltest";
    public string CommandDescription { get; set; } = "DAL Testing";
    public async Task Invoke(ControlConsole console, TelegramBotClient botClient)
    {
        using var uow = new UnitOfWork();
        var rep = uow.GetRepository<TelegramUser>();
        var entry = TelegramUser.Create(new Random().NextInt64(), "@TEST");
        rep.Add(entry);
        await uow.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

Invoke call:

```
public async Task StartConsole()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Type help to get available commands");
    while (_botWorked)
    {
        var msg = await Console.In.ReadLineAsync();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(msg)) continue;
        try
        {
            if (_commands.TryGetValue(msg.ToLower().Trim(), out var action))
            {
                await action.Invoke(this, _botClient);
            }
            else
            {
                ConsoleLogger.LogError("Command not found!");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ConsoleLogger.LogError($"{e.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

UPD: Repository code

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class, IBaseEntity
{
    private readonly DbSet<TEntity> _dbSet;

    public Repository(DbSet<TEntity> dbSet)
    {
        _dbSet = dbSet;
    }

    public async void AddAsync(TEntity entity)
    {
        await _dbSet.AddAsync(entity);
        UnitOfWork.cash[typeof(TEntity)] = await _dbSet.ToArrayAsync();
    }

    public void Add(TEntity entity)
    {
        _dbSet.Add(entity);
        UnitOfWork.cash[typeof(TEntity)] = _dbSet.ToArrayAsync();
    }

    public void Remove(TEntity entity)
    {
        _dbSet.Remove(entity);
        UnitOfWork.cash[typeof(TEntity)] = _dbSet.ToArrayAsync();
    }

    public void Update(TEntity entity)
    {
        _dbSet.Update(entity);
        UnitOfWork.cash[typeof(TEntity)] = _dbSet.ToArrayAsync();
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return UnitOfWork.cash[typeof(TEntity)] as IEnumerable<TEntity>;
    }
}
```

Comment: you are not using DependencyInjection?

Comment: yep, we have a regular console application (not asp.net) and so far we have not implemented DI mechanisms in our project. Will this help solve the problem?

Comment: I never tried to do something like that handling the depedency's myself. I personally would implement DI for the task. But i cannot say if that solves your problem.

Comment: What type of database are you using.  Excel or Access do not support sharing and what you are trying to do is to share the database. Excel and Access use the Drivers JET or ACCESS which have issues when shared.

Comment: It's not possible to give you a concrete answer without seeing the repository `Add` and UOW `SaveChangesAsync` implementations. From posted code, noticeable is that the UOW (hence the `DbContext`) is not disposed properly (calling async method w/o awaiting it).

Comment: This static dictionary of repositories is very weird. You reuse repositories that have DbSets from contexts that get disposed while the DbSet remains. Don't cache repositories and DbSets. Also, don't use this UoW/Repository layer. Instead, use DbContext/DbSet directly, they have the same semantics.

Comment: @jdweng I am using the latest version of Postgresql

Comment: @IvanStoev I have attached the `Repository` code.
I will take into account your comments about disposing UoW

Comment: @GertArnold Static dictionaries are suspicious of course, even though they seem to store objects rather than db sets (`cash.GetOrAdd(typeof(TEntity), rep.ToArray())` where `rep` is `DbSet`). Of course if there is no other code, since `object` could be anything, and no code using the objects stored in that dictionary is shown. What is stored in other static dictionary is unknown.

Comment: Postgrssql is just an intermediate app that can connect to different type of databases.  See : https://help.geneious.com/hc/en-us/articles/360045072371-How-to-set-up-a-Shared-Database-using-PostgreSQL?force_isolation=true

Comment: @pijio Ok, it shows what I was afraid of. Both `Add`, `Remove` and `Update` methods store unawaited `ToArrayAsync()` results into static dictionary.

Comment: @IvanStoev you are absolutely right. After making edits, everything began to work correctly. To my friend who wrote this code, i will say a couple of affectionate :).
If you want to specify this as an answer, I will mark it as correct.
Спасибо большое